# AWS service control policy for network access control list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to create AWS service control policy that prevents NACL entries with default route (0.0.0.0/0) which opens all the ports to internet except 80 and 443?

I created the below but it is not working as expected

```
{
“Version: “2012-10-17”,
“Statement”: [
{
   “Effect”: “Deny”,
   “Action”: [
       “ec2:CreateNetworkAclEntry”
   ],
   “Resource”: “*”,
   “Condition”: {
       “StringEquals”: {
                       “ec2:Attribute/CidrBlock”:[“0.0.0.0/0”],
                       “ec2:Attribute/CidrBlock”:[“::/0”],
         },
       “StringNotEquals”: {
                      “ec2:Attribute/PortRange”: [
                                            80,
                                            443
                         ]
         }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think this is possible via SCPs.

Checking [the SAR for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html), `CreateNetworkAclEntry` does not support the `ec2:Attribute` condition you're trying to use.